# What humanoid or monster races have a matriarchal society?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, races

What humanoid or monster races have a matriarchal society?

It is obvious **Drow** are:

> **RULE OF MATRIARCHS**
>
> *Females are the top figures in drow society. At the head of each house is someone who is a shrewd business operator, a skilled
>   tactician, a high priestess of Lolth, and probably also a merciless
>   assassin with blood on her hands. Unlike with many other races, female
>   drow are typically taller and more robust than males.*
>
> *To rise to the
>   top echelons of power, a female must first become a priestess of
>   Lolth. Then, to ascend to the status of high priestess, she must take
>   advantage of powerful connections or craft special alliances. The path
>   to ultimate power in drow society is never direct and is always paved
>   with death.*
>
> (Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, p. 51)

But, other than the Drow, **what are the other humanoid or monster races that have a matriarchal society in D&D?**

I am looking for any examples of this, from 5e or previous editions.

Comment: If you down vote, provide some feedback please. Just sayin' ... Here be Trolls! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Other than the well-known drow, some races which are predominantly matriarchal include:

- Beholders (*I, Tyrant*; worship a female deity and are led by "hive mothers", though according to *Lords of Madness* beholders are gender neutral, though they do lay eggs)
- Bhuka (*Sandstorm*, p.40)
- Blackspawn raiders (*Monster Manual IV*, p.132)
- Dune reapers (*Dark Sun Creature Catalog*, p.38)
- Gnolls (*Monster Manual IV*, p.70)
- Grung (*Monstrous Compendium: Greyhawk Appendix*)
- Hai nu (*Monstrous Compendium: Kara-Tur Appendix*)
- Hags (D&D 5e *Monster Manual* p.176; all hags, including green hags, night hags, and sea hags, are female)
- Kopru (*Monster Manual II*, p.135)
- Locathah (*Sea of Fallen Stars*, p.78)
- Medusas (*Monster Vault*, p.200)
- Munchkins (a joke race from *Dragon* #17)
- Omm-wa (*Savage Coast Monstrous Compendium*, p.81)
- Sand wurms (*Dragon* #296, p.80)
- Silats (*Monstrous Compendium: Al-Qadim Appendix*; all female)
- Skyzorr'n (*Dragon* #45. p.67)
- Swanmways (*From the Ashes*, Campaign Book, p.42)
- Werelions (*Monstrous Compendium: Al-Qadim Appendix*)
- Wild elves (some tribes only; *Races of Faerûn* p.44)

Answer (score 1):

From 3.5 or earlier, as I do not deal with 5, Abeils are a bee-like monstrous humanoid race with a Queen leader (MMII).  Giant Ants (MM3.5) have a Queen leader.  Hags and possibly nagas (MM3.5) seem to be solely female.  Stheins (Bastards&Bloodlines) are exclusively female.  Amazons (I do not remember the name of the Slayer’s Handbook) are exclusively female.  There are others, but I remember less about them except that various deities identify as female and might influence the society.

Comment: Hi @Amaranthine - could you add Hags onto your list as well? It's an oversight,but not present in either of the answers and not worth adding a new answer I don't think.